# How to mock an attribute of a callable instance in Python?

Tags: python, mocking

I have the following code, which I need to test:

```
uploader = AjaxFileUploader(backend=XLSXFileUploadBackend, obj=obj)
response = uploader(request)
...
response.content
```

I'd like to mock AjaxFileUploader and replace the `response.content` with some value.

I do the following:

```
@patch('guinness.apps.home.views.AjaxFileUploader')
def test_import_asset_to_bucket(self, mock_file_uploader):
    test_content = 'a:"1"'
    mock_file_uploader.return_value = MagicMock(return_value=MagicMock(content=test_content))
```

Is there more elegant way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get away with it just doing

```
mock_file_uploader.return_value.return_value.content = test_content
```

because the attribute `return_value` returns a new `Mock` object which is created on first access, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

I'm not sure this is much more elegant, though.